# ROS2 topic is limited to localhost

Tags: ros2, network

I have a ubuntu 18.04 installed board already setup with ros2 installed.
For some reason, ros2 topics are limited to its localhost and are not discoverable from outside like etho0 network.

I checked ROS_DOMAIN_ID but not working.
The board can connect to the internet via eth0 and I connect to the board with ssh no problem.

What settings can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY can do this.

See https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Configuring-ROS2-Environment.html#the-ros-localhost-only-variable

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my ubuntu may have enabled ufw for some reason.
just entering 'sudo ufw disable' in terminal solved the problem!